# Insanely large house numbers in TIGER data

Tags: tiger, united-states

I'm parsing the US TIGER data and I'm coming across huge house numbers.

example:
10100005 Thousand oaks drive, st johns, florida

Google maps, and open street maps - nominatim says this is valid! Im not from the US so im finding this very confusing, Any thoughts?

links:
https://www.google.com/maps/place/10100005+Thousand+Oaks+Dr/@30.2107612,-81.381784,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x88e437b298499921:0xbf10cbfa2e69c84a

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=10100005%20Thousand%20oaks%20drive,%20st%20johns,%20florida&format=xml&addressdetails=1

EDIT:
if the housenumber is > 100000, should i just drop it?

Comment: It sounds like a *I've got to put something here* data entry. Like forever used to be entered as 9/9/99. It sounds like a house that doesn't actually have an address but the capture operator *had* to put something in that field or the validation would fail - by using a very large number makes it easier to find again to fix, or it could be data corruption. Personally I would ignore it, but what's the benchmark.. 1k? 10k?

Comment: Five digit 'house' numbers are quite common. Beyond that you start seeing some coding systems that aren't just straight incremental numbers. I would take a look at some of those outliers and see how or if they relate to anything nearby.

Comment: Looking streetview all those houses seem to have names not numbers - but it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, there seems to be some logic behind it as the min and max would be similar, e.g a range of  47236001  to 47236099. but as iant said they have names not numbers. possibly the 47236 is a ID of some sorts and there is 001 to 099 houses there, but not numbered

Comment: They look like condos/apartments to me, so yes, it's possible (most likely) a unit number has been concatenated with a street number for the whole development. I note it's also a private street/closed community. I also note that while the address you typed says St Johns, the Google result city is Ponte Vedra Beach - St Johns is the county. Finally, a bit to the south is the Overseas Highway, and along that some addresses are referenced by mile marker. Those addresses can hit six digits, but it doesn't extend as far north as your example.